# Square video 1:1 ration ffmpeg command " Unrecognized option '‌​pr‌​eset'" not found at the time of crop video in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

**I have captured video successfully with normal android camera. Now i want to crop video with 1:1 ratio using ffmpeg libray command. But it gives me below error.**

**Version Used FFMPEG : compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'**

**Command :**
-`y, -i, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ZyfVideo/VID_20170916_093512.mp4, -vf, scale=720:ih*720/iw, crop=720:720,setdar=1:1,setsar=1:1, -threads, 5, -preset, ultrafast, -strict, experimental, -vcodec, libx264, -‌​pr‌​eset, ultrafast‌​, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ZyfVideo/VID_20170916_093521.mp4`

**Log Error :**

```
09-16 09:35:22.184 32149-32226/com.spoof.app D/FFmpeg: Running publishing updates method
09-16 09:35:22.451 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
09-16 09:35:22.451 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
09-16 09:35:22.465 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
09-16 09:35:22.487 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
09-16 09:35:22.490 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
09-16 09:35:22.491 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
09-16 09:35:22.493 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
09-16 09:35:22.494 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
09-16 09:35:22.497 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
09-16 09:35:22.498 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
09-16 09:35:22.499 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
09-16 09:35:22.549 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :Unrecognized option '‌​pr‌​eset'.
09-16 09:35:22.553 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Progress Video :Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
09-16 09:35:22.574 32149-32149/com.spoof.app D/NormalSquareFragment:  Failure Video :ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                       built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                       configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                       libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                       libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                       libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                       libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                       libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                       libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                       libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                       libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                     Unrecognized option '‌​pr‌​eset'.
                                                                     Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
09-
```

Answer (score 1):

The "r‌" in your duplicate `-‌​pr‌​eset, ultrafast‌​,` is encoded differently than the rest of the characters resulting in an unrecognized option.

Remove the second `-‌​pr‌​eset, ultrafast‌​,` and also remove the extra space after your scale filter.